# Invalid query results with mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to find a solution for my problem.

I basically have 3 tables - campaigns, users, campaign_user (pivot table - with campaign_id, user_id)

I have this query:

```
select * from `campaigns` 
where `id` = 91 
and (select count(*) 
    from `users` 
    inner join `campaign_user` on `users`.`id` = `campaign_user`.`user_id` 
    where `campaign_user`.`campaign_id` = `campaigns`.`id` 
    and `user_id` = 1) >= 1
```

That returns 0 results. I have checked that relevent row in `campaign_user` table exists.

Weird thing is that if I run the same query for another campaign id (89) it does return the expected result. Some campaign ids return as expected and some return 0.. weird and fraustrating.

This does not happen in production server which runs mysql 5.5

But it happens in my VM that runs mysql 5.7

I have no idea what is the cause of that. A help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the data is different between the two servers.

Comment: I have imported the same sql file. all rows are the same

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that the data is different on the two servers.  However, you can simplify the query, which is why I'm answering.  The `users` table is not needed in the subquery.  So:

```
select c.*
from `campaigns` c
where c `id` = 91  and
      (select count(*) 
       from campaign_user cu
       where cu.`campaign_id` = c.`id` and cu.user_id = 1
      ) >= 1;
```

This, in turn, can be simplified and made more efficient by using `exists` (or a `left join`) instead of `count(*)`:

```
select c.*
from campaigns c
where c id = 91  and
      exists (select 1
              from campaign_user cu
              where cu.campaign_id = c.id and cu.user_id = 1
             ) ;
```

Comment: So weird. Both of these queries returns 0 results. When I do `select * from campaign_user cu where cu.campaign_id = 91 and cu.user_id = 1` it does work so again this is so weird :/. 

Also, when I run `select c.* from campaigns c where (select count(*) from campaign_user cu where cu.campaign_id = c.id and cu.user_id = 1 ) >= 1` without `where id = 91` it returns a list of all campaigns related including 91 and 89 (remember: 89 does return ok)

Comment: btw - the original query is generated by laravel belongsToMany relation

Comment: @sUP . . . It's a shame that Laravel generates inferior queries.

Comment: Well I guess that's the best way to implement such a complicated ORM, taking into account every possible query you might run (and the app is built upon L4.2, They might changed it ever since). Anyway that's not laravel related since even the join query didn't work. I assume it's related to mysql 5.7 (I've setup another VM with 5.5 and it works). Thing is, we wanted to upgrade our production server to 5.7 but I guess we'll have to wait until we know more